# Searching Keywords in an API

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have an application where i retrieve information from an API and list it in a Flatlist.
Now i want to list only the results that are related to my search query, is it possible to do it with react native functions? Below is my current code, i managed to get access to the API and list the items so far but not the search field...
What you should be able to search is the county, so if you put the name of a county in the field, the data related to the county should be displayed.

```
import React, { useEffect,useState } from "react";
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Button,
  TextInput,
  ScrollView,
  FlatList,
  ActivityIndicator,
} from "react-native";



const myApp = (props) => {
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);



  useEffect(() => {
        fetch('dummy Data')
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((json) => setData(json.features))
      .catch((error) => console.error(error))
      .finally(() => setLoading(false));
  }, []);

  
  return (
    
    <View style={main.container}>
      <View style={[main.divs, main.divEins]}>
        <Text style={main.text}>
          City
        </Text>
      </View>

      <View style={main.divDrei}>
        <TextInput
          inputData={data}
          style={main.input}
          onChangeText={inputData}
          placeholder="seach for city"
        ></TextInput>

        <Button
          title="Seach"
          onPress={() => console.log(data.features)}
        />
      </View>

      <View style={{ flex: 1, padding: 24 }}>
      {isLoading ? <ActivityIndicator/> : (
        <FlatList
          data={data}
          keyExtractor={({ id }, index) => id}
          renderItem={({ item }) => (
          <Text>{item.attributes.BL}, {item.attributes.county},{item.attributes.deaths}</Text>
          )}
        />
      )}
    </View>
    </View>
  );
};
```

Comment: Which field are you trying to search with ? and how do you set the filters ?

Comment: @GuruparanGiritharan i edited my initial post for more clarification

Comment: Please check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a state value for the filter that you type into the text box and filter the array that you provide as a prop to the flatlist. This will keep your data from api untouched and will allow you to do filter at client side. You can check the code here

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Button,
  TextInput,
  ScrollView,
  FlatList,
  ActivityIndicator,
} from 'react-native';

const myApp = (props) => {
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [searchedData, setSearchedData] = useState([]);
  //save your filter as a string
  const [filterCountry, setFilterCountry] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('dummyAPI.json')
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((json) => setData(json.features))
      .catch((error) => console.error(error))
      .finally(() => setLoading(false));
  }, []);

  return (
    <View style={main.container}>
      <View style={[main.divs, main.divEins]}>
        <Text style={main.text}>
          Hallo here you can see information about your favorite city
        </Text>
      </View>

      <View style={main.divDrei}>
        <TextInput
          value={filterCountry}
          style={main.input}
          onChangeText={setFilterCountry}
          placeholder="seach for city"
        />

        <Button title="Seach" onPress={() => console.log(data.features)} />
      </View>

      <View style={{ flex: 1, padding: 24 }}>
        {isLoading ? (
          <ActivityIndicator />
        ) : (
          <FlatList
            data={
              !filterCountry ? data : data.filter((item) =>
                    item.attributes.county.includes(filterCountry)
                  )
            }
            keyExtractor={({ id }, index) => id}
            renderItem={({ item }) => (
              <Text>
                {item.attributes.BL}, {item.attributes.county},
                {item.attributes.deaths}
              </Text>
            )}
          />
        )}
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};
```

Comment: is it possible to render only a specific amount of data from the API ? As far as i know the default value of initialNumToRender is supposed to be 10, but in my example it renders all items somehow

Comment: Flatlist renders only the items that are currently shown in the screen, however its better if you can filter your api on backend to save network load. initialNumToRender is amount it renders in first batch not the count it should show

Comment: So initialNumToRender doesnt effect the amoung of data that is being displayed? Because trying to limit the amount of displayed with initialNumToRender doesnt work for me. I just put initialNumToRender={5} into the Flatlist bracket but the results are the same.

Comment: initialNumToRender is first set of objects to be rendered you will have to use array slice to get the top 5 and show

Comment: @yeah iam trying to slice the data but it doesnt work as intended,  data={ data.slice(0,10) &&
              !filterCountry ? data : data.filter((item) =>
                    item.attributes.county.includes(filterCountry)
                  )
            }

Comment: do you want to slice the main array or the array thats shown ?

Comment: i have an additional question or should i open a new question about opening the items from the searchfield in a new modal

Comment: If its a totally different question better create a new one

Comment: Ok thank you anyway, ive created a new one as the quesion is totally different. Ive marked ur question as the accepted one

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is have the `onChangeText` of the search `TextInput` be be a function that updates/filters your `data` state. The new `data` will then be rendered in the FlatList.

```
// we introduce this to avoid modifying our original data set
const [filteredData, setFilteredData] = useState([]);

handleSearch = (text) => {
  // looking at the api and your post update, features is a list of items with attributes objects, and each has county
  // check for substring
  const filtered = data.filter(item => item.attributes.county.includes(text));
  setFilteredData(filtered);
}
...

<TextInput
  inputData={filteredData}
  style={main.input}
  onChangeText={(text) => handleSearch(text)}
  placeholder="seach for city"
></TextInput>
...

<FlatList
  data={data} // <- on re-render this will be updated
...
```

Comment: how can i filter the data based on the county, say i write a county in the searchfield, how is it possible to extract the string ?

Comment: `onChangeText` will pass the typed in text as a parameter to the function we provide. We pass that text to our handler, and then do a `filter` operation on the data array. I updated my code to reflect that.

Comment: @Guruparan Giritharan answer has something similar, he is just filtering directly in the `FlatList`.

This reminds me. We don't want to corrupt our original data, so our `FlatList` data should be based on our filtered data. I will update my code to avoid confusion.